# Getting the key of a key/value pair in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, key-value

I created a key-value pair using the arrow operator in Scala/Spark:

```
val picardsShip = "Picard" -> "Enterprise-D"
```

I extracted the value by using `println(picardsShip._2)` and that returns the value `Enterprise-D`, as expected. However, I want to extract the key in this case to get `Picard`. When I type `picardsShip.` in the IntelliJ IDEA editor that I am using, I don't see anything suggesting an obvious attribute or method to get the key. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It's just `println(picardsShip._1)`. `_1` takes the first element in tuple.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik I am not looking for the first element. I am looking for the `key` instead of the `value` of that `key`. That applies to ANY element that I want to refer to. Thank you.

Comment: This is a Scala tuple. Nothing specific to Spark

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 You are right. But I am using that Scala code in Spark.

Comment: You could look for a key in a Map, not in a Tuple2. It's a sequence of elements. You can get an element for its index. For example: `scala> picardsShip.productElement(0)
res0: Any = Picard`

Comment: @Chema Nice. I guess there is no built-in way to do it using tuples as the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Careful here, you haven't created a key/value pair. You've created a tuple. When you use the REPL, you can see what's happening:

```scala
scala> val picardsShip = "Picard" -> "Enterprise-D"
picardsShip: (String, String) = (Picard,Enterprise-D)
```

to access the first value, use what  @Krzysztof Atłasik suggested and use `._1`:

```scala
scala> picardsShip._1
res1: String = Picard
```

Yes, you can create a key/value pair using the `->` operator, but if you want it to operate on it like you have a key/value pair - you have to be a bit more specific by wrapping it in a map. And then you no longer have 1 key/value pair, but theoretically none to many key value pairs, which means you have basically a kind of `Seq` which is what Scala is really built around. The `Map` gives you access to an API that basically says "okay, here is a series of items that can be treated as key-value pairs" and will allow you to operate on it as you would expect key-value pairs to look at:

```scala
scala> val shipMap: Map[String, String] = Map(("Picard" -> "Enterprise-D"))
shipMap: Map[String,String] = Map(Picard -> Enterprise-D)

scala> shipMap("Picard")
res2: String = Enterprise-D

scala> shipMap.keys.head
res3: String = Picard

scala> shipMap.foreach( kv => println(kv._1))
Picard
```